# Wrapper around web-app under Windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, web-applications

I have an application with web interface. Unfortunately, it has all disadvantages of being a web page:

- It doesn't have a standalone window, so users cannot manage it via the taskbar.
- Users see the address line with something like 'http://localhost:8080' that is not a good idea for home users.
- If users click on a tray icon, there is no way to activate the tab in a browser, which contain the application interface.

So, it would be nice to have a wrapper application with a browser within.

In case of IE I know it's possible to create a window with Trident ActiveX component. But what if it's Windows XP with IE6 but installed latest Chrome? I'd like to prefer Chrome since it supports a lot more features which the user will never see.

So, is there a way to wrap a page into Chrome/Firefox and make it look like a standalone application, if one of them is presented in the user's system? (The application shouldn't install anything large, so Chromium build is not an option).

P.S. I'm not interested in supporting other platforms than Windows.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Chrome Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app).

I hope helps you.